# Open a directory in the default file manager and select a file

Tags: xdg

In a program which I am writing I want to offer the functionality to open the directory where the file which I am currently processing is located and automatically select that file (so that the user does not need to search for it).

I know that I can open a directory in the default file manager using

```
xdg-open /path/to/directory
```

I know that I can open a directory in nautilus and select a file using

```
nautilus /path/to/file.txt
```

I *thought* that I could use

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

to get the default file manager and - if it is nautilus - call it as shown above.
But, despite the fact that nautilus is the default on my system (`xdg-open` opens nautilus and so does the places menu in the gnome shell), `xdg-mime` returns `Thunar.desktop`.
(I have tried `find / -name Thunar.desktop -mount 2>/dev/null` but it did not find anything.)

Also, I do not know how to open a directory and select a sub*directory* in nautilus (with the above mentioned approach it would open the subdirectory).

How can I open a directory in the default filemanager *and* select a file in that directory (if selecting a directory, too, was possible that would be great, but for this application not needed)
or at least find out the default filemanager so that I can call it directly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**1.** To open a directory and select a subdirectory/file in nautilus:

```
nautilus --select path/to/file/or/directory
```

From [nautilus(1) man page](https://www.mankier.com/1/nautilus):

> **-s, --select** 
>     Select specified URI in parent folder.

**2.** `xdg-mime` returns `Thunar.desktop` but `xdg-open` opens `nautilus`

`xdg-mime` uses `mimeapps.list` to determine the default application to use.

Separate `mimeapps.list` files exist to handle user-specific, system-specific and distribution-specific requirements. Their lookup order can be found over [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.1.html).

`mimeapps.list` lists default applications for a given mimetype under [Default Applications] section. It allows to list multiple default applications in their decreasing order of preference. For example :

```
[Default Applications]
mimetype1 = default1.desktop;default2.desktop;
```

where *mimetype1* is the mime type and **.desktop* are the desktop files.

`xdg-open` searches for desktop file down the lookup order, across the preference list till it finds a valid desktop file. If no such file is found across all the files then the most preferred one according to the associations is chosen and is used as default application.

So in case of our example, let us suppose `default1.desktop` is not present on our system, so `xdg-open` will try to open our file using `default2.desktop`. However, `xdg-mime` returns  `default1.desktop` which is the first entry in our `mimeapps.list` file.

In your case `default1.desktop` must be `Thunar.desktop` hence the output. However it is not installed on your system. So `xdg-open` opens your file/directories using `nautilus` which is present on your system. To verify this, you can check your `mimeapps.list` file for line containing `inode/directory`. For Ubuntu 17.10, the location of `mimeapps.list` file is : `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`

**NOTE:** The complete algorithm to determine 'Default Applications' can be found [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.1.html).

Comment: In case something has remained unanswered or if there is any confusion, drop a comment.

Comment: Your excellent answer looked like a question on the first spot (what is a delete reason), it could mislead reviewers, so I edited it a little bit. Feel free to rollback if it is not okay.

Comment: @peterh Thanks for the edit! I will keep it in mind for future answers.

Comment: +1. Thanks a lot for your answer. The first part works perfectly. The second part together with [this specification explaining which values are assumed if the environment variables are not set](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) explains why Thunar is returned.

Comment: However, I still can not retrace why Nautilus is started because it is not specified in a `mimeapps.list`. Can you explain what these associations are in "if after all files are handled, we have not yet found a default application, select the most-preferred application (according to associations) that supports the type"? Do you know a way how to find out which program will be started automatically whitout needing to reimplement this algorithm?

Comment: A MIMETYPE is defined by type of document followed by its extension. Suppose you are trying to open a `.ogg` file but no default application is found. So the system will look into the type of document and try to open it with the application that is most often used to open that type of documents ( `video` in this case ). For this it will check the entries that have document type mentioned as `video`.

Comment: This answer is difficult to understand. So it is possible or not to open a directory in the default file manager selecting a file, just as Windows `explorer /select filename` does?

Answer (score 8):

You may want to consider using dbus to open your file as it is quickly becoming more popular.

The concept of a "default" file manager only really exists if you are solely focused on `xdg-mime`, however in dbus land, (and indeed the majority of applications out there) the story takes a different twist, and the concept of a "default" file manager ceases to exist.

This is how you open a file (`/home/me/path/to/folder/or/file`) in the (default?) file manager, using dbus:

```bash
dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 --type=method_call /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItems array:string:"file:///home/me/path/to/folder/or/file" string:""
```

What this command does is to look for any dbus service which implements the `org.freedesktop.FileManager1` interface, and calls it with the path to the file you wish to open.

The reason I put a question mark after *default* is because dbus does not respect the concept of "default" file manager; all it does is send the call to the first service it finds that implements the interface and lets it handle the operation. Now it may be that the application it picks is your "default" file manager, but that's not always a guarantee.

Most modern applications will use `dbus` by default and then fallback to `xdg-mime` if the dbus call fails, so this is what I'd suggest you do.

---

#### Selecting multiple files

This can be achieved by adding a comma between the file names:

```bash
dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 --type=method_call /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItems array:string:"file:///home/me/path/to/folder/or/file1","file:///home/me/path/to/folder/or/file2" string:""
```

Depending on the file manager that is used by dbus, you may get different behaviour when opening multiple files. [Some](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364997/open-a-directory-in-the-default-file-manager-and-select-a-file/581215#comment1469712_581215) users have complained that Thunar opens a new window (or new tab) for each file selected.

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 21.10. But what is the last `string:""` part? At first I omitted it and that caused an error.

Comment: @DamnVegetables the last part corresponds to a startup id as you can see [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/file-manager-interface/). I couldn't really find anything regarding how it is meant to be used, but I used the empty string because that's exactly what firefox uses when it sends the dbus message. You can observe this for yourself by running the following command in a separate terminal and trying to open a file location from firefox: `dbus-monitor interface=org.freedesktop.FileManager1`

Comment: Is it possible to select multiple files this way?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen yes, you can use the syntax `array:string"file:///home/me/path/to/folder/or/file1","file:///home/me/path/to/folder/or/file2"`. Basically add a comma between the file names, and quote them. I added an example

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that `org.freedesktop.FileManager1` goes to Thunar on my system and it implements multiple file selection by opening one window per selected file instead of selecting multiple files in a single window. I wasn't expecting to see multiple windows pop open with a single `dbus-send` message.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen If you want to change what `org.freedesktop.FileManager1` points to, see my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581233/44793). I use KDE and their default file manager (Dolphin) opens a window with the files specified, highlighted.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen thunar also has an option to open new thunar windows in tabs if there if there is an existing window. This may help with the multiple window issue

Comment: That might work for some cases. I would want to select multiple items in a single window from CLI so that I can then drag-and-drop all the files at once using the GUI from that on. If I get one file per window or tab it doesn't help at all.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen sounds like a good time to open a feature request for [thunar](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/-/issues). Having looked at how other file managers like [nemo](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/184204ad4871420e19e2dc0a51d81780f06eed0f/src/nemo-freedesktop-dbus.c#L56), and nautilus implement this, it is clear that there isn't a lot out there that get it right, apart from [Dolphin](https://github.com/KDE/dolphin/blob/19a59fad5f9f1d81245af9b294db943d7dcf7e02/src/dbusinterface.cpp#L41)

Comment: I agree. It seems that Dolphin is pretty aggressive re-using existing windows which might not always be the true intent of the user: https://github.com/KDE/dolphin/blob/41bd0d27fa6f6e9953751dfed6865460082ade6d/src/global.cpp#L88

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen yea dolphin does reuse existing windows, but only if the files to select have the same parent folder as any of those existing windows.

Answer (score 1):

@smac89, I wrote an AWK script using your string and saved it to `~/.local/bin/xdg-select-file` for opening directories and selecting files for any paths/URIs with GIO binary for getting their URIs.
The Syntax of this script is:

`xdg-select-file /full/path/file`

or:

`xdg-select-file ../relative/path/file`

or:

`xdg-select-file file:///URI%20TO/path/file`

You may use single or double quotes for the file path.

And this is code:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
    for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++){
        xdg_select_file(ARGV[i])
    }
}

function xdg_select_file(infile,    cmd_get,cmd_run){
    cmd_get="LC_MESSAGES=C gio info " infile
    while((cmd_get|getline)>0){
        if($1~/^uri:/){
        cmd_run="dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 --type=method_call /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItems array:string:\""$2"\" string:\"\""
        break
        }
    }
    system(cmd_run)
    close(cmd_run)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `gdbus`; this also allows to open the file manager even if filepath or filename contains comma and so doesn't work in `dbus-send`.

Example:

```shell
FILE="path to file/file" #contains comma

gdbus call --session --dest org.freedesktop.FileManager1 --object-path /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 --method org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItems "['file://$FILE']" ""
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you should be able to following for both files and directories:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright 2024 Mikko Rantalainen <mikko.rantalainen@iki.fi>
# License: MIT <https://opensource.org/license/mit/>
set -e

urlencode()
{
    printf "%s" "$@" | perl -pe 's/([^A-Za-z0-9.\/:])/sprintf("%%%02X", ord($1))/seg'
}

if test -z "$1"; then
    exec xdg-open .
fi

PREFIX=""
FILES=""
for f in "$@"; do
    abs="$(realpath -e "$f")"
    ef="$(urlencode "$abs")"
    bef="$(printf "file://%q" "$ef")"
    FILES="$FILES$PREFIX$bef"
    PREFIX=","
done

dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 --type=method_call /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItems array:string:$FILES string:''
```

However, in practice this works well for one file only and the destination may or may not be your expected file manager. You can change the `--dest` to match your expected file manager if multiple implement the interface `org.freedesktop.FileManager1`. For example, if you use Caja, then you could use `--dest=org.mate.Caja` instead of `--dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1`. You can try listing possible destination names with `busctl` or `qdbus`.

I'd expect the file manager to select multiple files in a single window when passed multiple files. For my system, only Caja and Thunar seem to implement this API and both implement multiple files by opening equally many windows and selecting one file per window. For a single file or directory, this will result in the expected behavior of opening a file manager window with the given file or directory preselected.

If this script is called without parameters, it will open the current working directory in file manager using `xdg-open`.