# Clean way to run proper file manager from Firefox on Linux

Tags: linux, kde, firefox, cinnamon, d-bus

As many of mans known, currently solution with `defaults.conf` and `mimetypes.cache` does not work.

Firefox currently uses D-bus to activate service `org.freedesktop.FileManager1` to handle "Open containing folder" action and so on.

In case, when many service files installed (nemo and dolphin, for example) and no daemon running (`dolphin --daemon` or `/usr/bin/nemo --no-default-window`) there is no clean way to select preferred file manager.

On my system looks like selected first service file sorted in alphabetical order. So, on KDE system Firefox handles folders via Nemo.

I see currently at least two solutions, both seems as hack:

1. make a symlink:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.dolphin.FileManager1.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services/00_preferred_org.freedesktop.FileManager1.service
   ```

   (don't forget to kill currently running file manager daemons or relogin session)
2. Early pre-run needed `org.freedesktop.FileManager1` handler. Like `dolphin --daemon` in `~/.profile` under proper conditions.

It there more clean way?

PS try to execute file manager without Firefox:

```
dbus-send --session \
          --print-reply \
          --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 \
          /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 \
          org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowFolders \
              array:string:"file:/" string:""
```

Comment: maybe Mozilla made a poor choice, see: https://polywogsys.livejournal.com/309405.html - he gives a nice fix in case of common error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cleaner way exists and it is similar to your first solution. Instead of mucking around in the system services folder, you can create your symlink in `~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/`.

According to the [dbus docs](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-daemon.1.html), dbus will look in `$XDG_DATA_HOME/dbus-1/services` (among others) for any service files and load them. Although the docs does not specify the order in which the folders are searched, I just tried this on my machine and it worked in finding the filemanager service I wanted to use.

---

In my case, I wanted to use `nautilus` as the default file manager in xfce instead of thunar, so I used this command to make it work:

```
ln -s /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.FileManager1.service ~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.FileManager1.service
```

#### Other sources:

https://polywogsys.livejournal.com/309405.html

Answer (score 1):

original `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.dolphin.FileManager1.service` contained something like

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.FileManager1
Exec=/usr/bin/dolphin --daemon
SystemdService=plasma-dolphin.service
```

I replaced it with

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.FileManager1
Exec=QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum /usr/bin/dolphin --daemon
```

and it works like a charm.

Though, editing file in /usr directly isn't the best approach and I should've override it from ~/.local, I guess