# Running my desired file manager from within the web browser

Tags: linux, d-bus, browser, file-browser

I would like to run *Nemo* instead of *Xfce*'s default file browser, in my browser.

Per [Clean way to run proper file manager from Firefox on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487054/clean-way-to-run-proper-file-manager-from-firefox-on-linux/581229#581229) I tried to do:

```
$ mkdir --parents ~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/
$ ln --symbolic /usr/share/dbus-1/services/nemo.FileManager1.service ~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.FileManager1.service
```

To test to see which file manager opens, I ran:

```
$ dbus-send --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 --type=method_call /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItems array:string:"file:///home/" string:""
```

I then rebooted, but nothing changed. I even copied a few more service files and updated their `Name` field:

- `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.FileManager.service`
- `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.Thunar.FileManager1.service`

Again nothing changed and *Thunar* still opens. It seems like my settings are entirely being ignored.

Any ideas on whats going on, or how can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at `/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf`, which I didn't modify. This contains `<standard_session_servicedirs />`. Per [dbus-daemon](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-daemon.1.html) this means `~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/` is included and should take preference over services in `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/`.

There was nothing relevant in `dbus.service` logs.

Some googling and [Changing DBUS FileManager1 to Krusader](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/dbus/2021-January/017964.html) says:

> There's no solution for auto-launching. If you want a per-desktop override of a given service, start it early. So your question is to your desktop system and to your application in particular: have them launch early and claim the org.freedesktop.FileManager1 service name. And don't quit.

Indeed, looking at my running *D-Bus* services, there's already a `org.freedesktop.FileManager1`.

```py
import dbus

session_bus = dbus.bus.BusConnection('unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus')
for service in session_bus.list_names():
    print(service)
```

Looking at my processes, I have `/usr/bin/Thunar --gapplication-service` running.

This was started by `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.Thunar.FileManager1.service` with the contents:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.FileManager1
Exec=/usr/bin/Thunar --gapplication-service
SystemdService=thunar.service
```

Upon killing this process, my config in `~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.FileManager1.service` works.

There is still no way to disable *D-Bus* services per [Need to provide standardized way to disable services started by dbus (#70) · Issues · dbus / dbus · GitLab](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/dbus/dbus/-/issues/70#note_695257).

So in order to fix this issue, in addition to including `~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.FileManager1.service`, I just killed any `Thunar` processes on login. Now *Nemo* shows up when I open it in my web browser.